# Updating Mule application through the mmc

Tags: mule, esb, mule-studio

I'm trying to update an application in the evaluation version of Mule ESB EE.
I upload to repository, create a new deployment and start it.

But the server is still serving up the old .xml

I've tried stopping and starting the service, creating a new one with another name and whatnot but still no luck. Only thing that works is hot-deploying (drop the zip file into the directory) but that has the drawback of not showing up in the mmc.

Checking the Mulesoft forums yields one similar question that was posted 8 months ago (around october 2012) with no resolution.

Has anyone here run into this and knows of a fix?

***Edit***

I figured out a workaround:

1. When exporting the project in Mule Studio, instead of "Publish to Application Repository" select "Mule Studio Project to Mule......" (the zip file)
2. Using the mmc interface go to deployments tab, select repository and create new.
3. Import the .zip file you just created and deploy as usual.

(Also added this answer to [the Mulesoft forum question](http://forum.mulesoft.org/mulesoft/topics/old_flow_xml_stuck_in_repository))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the workaround is all there is so I'm marking this as solved with that as the solution

Workaround:

1. When exporting the project in Mule Studio, instead of "Publish to Application Repository" select "Mule Studio Project to Mule......" (the zip file)
2. Using the mmc interface go to deployments tab, select repository and create new.
3. Import the .zip file you just created and deploy as usual.